# Tailwindcss fluid grid

Tags: css-grid, tailwind-css

I generally use this line of css to get a fluid grid for items with 20rem width:

'''
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20rem, 1fr));
'''

Can i use css utility classes to do this oris there any way to extend it so that it can do this ?

Comment: You can [create your own utility class](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-new-utilities) for it.

Answer (score 4):

There's no utility class that can do this. If you wanted to extend Tailwind and add a custom utility class for grid-template-columns, you could add something like this in your tailwind.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      gridTemplateColumns: {
        'fluid': 'repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20rem, 1fr))',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You could then use the class `grid-cols-fluid`.

Comment: actually very good point